# building a huge-oldish .net program under linux

Tags: c#, asp.net, linux, msbuild, mono

I started working for a company which has a huge .NET software with parts using different technologies (webforms, mvc, ASMX web services), compiled using MSBUILD 14 (VS 2015) on a CI platform.

And they have the brillant idea to migrate all of this to Linux(Redhat)!

I can tell that this is a very bad idea. But I need concrete reasons, probably a few of them. So I decided to looking at mono, to see if it is really capable of doing this. Can you give few subjective/objective ideas on mono and on why this migration is not a good idea?

thank you in advance

Comment: I've been using mono for more than 15 years. It's good for certain things and bad for others. In 2020, I would be more worried about their use of webforms than the use of Linux. I would suggest to use .Net Core on Linux which is officially supported, but you may need to find out which of these apps would work.

Comment: @JCOlivares so even if I can safely build this codebase with mono, will it work on IIS for example? because I read that mono uses apache server.

Comment: IIS doesn't run on Linux. One way to run mono apps is by using mod_mono for apache, but my guess is that is no longer supported (citation needed). Another way is to run the application by using xsp behind a webserver like nginx. Too many variables to give a concrete answer.

Comment: @JCOlivares thank you, my question was actually (I know how it sounds..) if a source code compiled with mono (on linux) will ever run with IIS on windows?

Comment: It could/should. Mono generates IL (CIL / MSIL). See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Intermediate_Language